# tracking controller with fixed control bandwidth in h infinity framework

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I want to synthesize an $H_\infty$ tracking controller for a second-order system.

The system is subject to noise on position, velocity, and acceleration.

If we look at the typical framework with the generalized plant $P$

[image: generalized plant]

to me it looks that the noise signals, are part of the $w$ exogenous input, while the tracking error is the $z$ output. I measure position and velocity, which are corrupted by noise and form the output $v$, used as input to the controller $K$.

Inside the generalized plant "P" there are the corresponding weighting function indicating the frequency content of those noise signals.

Where does the reference signal go here? (is it another $w$ input?), and how can I fix the closed-loop bandwidth of this controller? e.g., such that I can track signals until 5 Hz, while the controller does not react to input signals with frequency larger than 100 Hz?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, reference signal is also exogenous input. For the bandwidth you want to shape the channel w to z that corresponds to reference-> tracking error. Hence you can multiply that channel with the appropriate filter inverse.

Comment: thanks! I suppose I can use a low-pass filter as weighting function there, right? to avoid that the controller tries to track signals which switch too fast.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it works. But keep in mind that the product of filter and the plant is minimized. Hence the inverse